# Tag for trying to do the same in other software

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tags

Sometimes I see questions as "... *in ArcMap I used to do this process, but in QGIS I don't know how to do it*... " or question like [Loading GeoTiff with specified color band from ArcGIS to QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/235026)

Is there a tag to identify this kind of questions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As [@PolyGeo has said](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4634/115), that would be a meta Tag.

If you think about it, there is no need of such a Tag. I, as an answer writer am not concerned with whether the OP knows how to do the process with Software X. All I'm concerned with is explaining how to do the process in Software Y.

Hence the Question should be titled: `How to do <Process> in <Software Y>?` and just tag Software Y in the Question, along with any other appropriate Tag.

Comment: +1 although I diverge slightly by preferring a more concise title like `<Processing> in <Software Y>?`

Answer (score 3):

There is not a tag to identify this kind of question, and I do not think that there should be.

If one were created it would seem to be a [meta tag](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/08/07/the-death-of-meta-tags/) which are generally advised against.